# How can I reset Excel window position?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

When I open an Excel spreadsheet, often (not everytime / on every document / ...?) the window opens with a configuration I've apparently used at some point:

- Almost as wide as the screen
- Almost as high as the screen, but starting about 1.5cm below the upper screen bound.

This way, it looks maximized, but isn't. So when I want to close the spreadsheet (push the mouse to up right corner, click the "X"), I very often actually close the window *behind* the spreadsheet instead (followed by curses and investigation on what has been there that I've just closed).

Is there any way to let Excel forget such a configuration or replace it by a "more obviously not maximized" one?

Comment: I thought it just used the last used window size

Comment: I thought that as well, but it seems to not do that "sometimes". :-/

Comment: It’s even more fun if you are in virtual machine, and close (kill) the machine instead of Excel… looking forward to a solution!